# FB Graph API is not responding to Public Server

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, server

I am trying to access my Page's likes using appid, access token in php using file_get_contents(). 
The link is : `https://graph.facebook.com/<page_name>?access_token=<my_Access_token>|<my_app_id>&fields=likes`

My FB application is in development mode however, it gives output on localhost which I am running through MAMP.

**Problem**

My website is hosted on BYETHOST which uses PHP5.4 and `allow_url_fopen` is ON.

**Code**

```
<?php
$json_url ='https://graph.facebook.com/<page_name>?access_token=<access_token>|<appid>&fields=likes';
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json_output = json_decode($json);
//Extract the likes count from the JSON object
if($json_output->likes){
    $likes = $json_output->likes;
    echo $likes;
}else{
    echo 'FB Request Error!';
}
?>
```

This code is not working on BYETHOST however, if I change the link to `https://qrng.anu.edu.au/API/jsonI.php?length=1&type=uint8` it gives output perfectly on both localhost and BYETHOST.

What could be the problem here ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: There isn't any output for FB graph API. The output is 'FB Request Error'. @chris